# Mac OS X High Sierra - Arduino communication with NodeJs works only in debug with break point on write

Tags: node.js, macos, serial-port, arduino-uno, macos-high-sierra

I've tried a simple demo with NodeJs running on my Mac that want to send and receive data from an Arduino connected to the serial port.

I used the *serialport* npm's package.

This is the NodeJs code.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');

var portName = "/dev/cu.usbmodem1421";

var myPort = new SerialPort(portName, 9600);

var Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
var parser = new Readline();
myPort.pipe(parser);

myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
parser.on('data', readSerialData);
myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
myPort.on('error', showError);

function showPortOpen() {
    console.log('port open. Data rate: ' + myPort.baudRate);
    myPort.write(':FF0807#');

}

function readSerialData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

function showPortClose() {
    console.log('port closed.');
}

function showError(error) {
    console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
}
```

And this is the Arduino code.

```
String readString;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);
    if (Serial.available() >0) {
      char c = Serial.read();
      readString += c;
    } 
  }

  if(readString == ":FF0807#") {
    Serial.println("received!");
    delay(100);

  }
  readString = "";

}
```

As you can see, the NodeJs script, open the serial communication and than, when it is opened, it writes the string *:FF0807#* on it.

The Arduino, on the other side, reads the string and responds with a *received!* string.

My NodeJs script works only in debug and only if I put a breakpoint on the line that send data to the Arduino.

I've tried with some timeout before send data but also this does not work.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem. The timeout showed in the package documentation (400ms) isn't enough to give time to the Arduino Uno to initialize the Serial. Before I posted the question, I tried also a timeout of 1 second but even this isn't enough.

All working correctly with a timeout of 3/5 seconds. I personally prefer the second way described in the official documentation that is to wait a "ready" message sent by the Arduino before send the first command.